# How to get integer value from coredata to load to text

Tags: ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I am trying to get

```
[self.cellTextField setText:[self.person valueForKey:@"cellnumber"]];
```

to load the cell number.

It is an integer from a Core Data person entity. Right now it crashes and will only load a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data stores numbers as NSNumbers, and NSNumber has a method called stringValue. Try this:

```
[self.cellTextField setText:[[self.person valueForKey:@"cellnumber"] stringValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can tell without an error log to go off of:

You have a label in your `UITableViewCell` that you need to display the value of the `cellnumber` key in `self.person`.

Here I am assuming that you aren't making some basic mistake (like `self.person` being an array, etc), and that the value of the `cellnumber` key is an **`int`**.

Since the value of that key is an `int`, you can't just give it to something that expects a string. You'll need to convert it to an `NSString` first. Here's how:

```
NSString *personCellNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.person valueForKey:@"cellnumber"]];

[self.cellTextField setText:personCellNumberString];
```

Comment: when i save say 111 to cellnumber , it spits it out as 155702688?

Comment: am i supposed to have cell number as a 32 bit int? thanks @Undo

Comment: format specifies type int but argument has type "id" is the thing i get too